# How to prevent JDBC from creating database?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

Task: in case of database not being available or damaged, look for backup and if it exists, copy it to be main database.

Currently when I connect, in case there is no database, it is automatically being created:

```
Connection c = null;
try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/home/accounting/DB/myDatabase.sqlite");
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
    return c;
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    return null;
}
```

I want to prevent database from being created, determine if database is not there or damaged, and trigger check for availability of backup database.

Comment: JDBC doesn't create anything. The MySQLLite driver may.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the file of your database exit or not :

```
String dbPath = "src/home/accounting/DB/myDatabase.sqlite";
File dbFile = new File(dbPath);
if (dbFile.exists()) {
    //database already exist don't create it again
} else {
    Connection c = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbPath);
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
        return c;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```